# Table with two rows, one row only for title - HTML

Tags: html, html-table, rows

I am trying to make a table with two rows and multiple columns in html. I want the first row to have only one space instead of two for each column. It will be a title space for the entire table.

Example: (Specifications is the Title)

```
[Specifications]
[Power         ][200 Lumens                       ]
[Lamp          ][4 Ultrabright LEDs, Maxbright LED]
[Burn Time     ][150 Hours                        ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is just one section to the table (*viz*: all the table contents are specifications) I'd probably use a `caption` element to mark that up:

```
<table>
  <caption>Specifications</caption>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Power</th>
    <td>200 Lumens</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Lamp</th>
    <td>4 Ultrabright LEDs, Maxbright LED</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Burn Time</th>
    <td>150 Hours</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If there are multiple sections, I'd use the spanning (`<th scope="col" colspan="2">...` table headers:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col" colspan="2">Specifications</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Power</th>
    <td>200 Lumens</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Lamp</th>
    <td>4 Ultrabright LEDs, Maxbright LED</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Burn Time</th>
    <td>150 Hours</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col" colspan="2">Some Other Section</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Foo</th>
    <td>Bar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Baz</th>
    <td>Qux</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zggcp/)

Answer (score 4):

#### Use `colspan="2"`

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Specifictaions</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Power</td>
        <td>200 Lumens</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Lamp</td>
        <td>4 Ultrabright LEDs, Maxbright LED</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Burn Time</td>
        <td>150 Hours</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tCvBn/

#### Screenshot

[image]

Comment: <td colspan="2"></td>? or <td colspan="2">?

Comment: You need a closing tag. The first one. Inside that, give the title. I prefer you to use `<th colspan="2">Specifications</th>` as it is a heading. See the screenshot.

Comment: Thoe non-spanning first columns should also be `th`: `<th scope="row">...`

Comment: @steveax Don't get you. `scope`? Ah, the left side ones huh?

Comment: Yes, [scope](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H63). The top heading should have `scope="col"`

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you're looking for! Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NuQ2D/1/)

```
<table width="100" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Foo</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Foo</td>
    <td>Bar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Foo</td>
    <td>Bar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Foo</td>
    <td>Bar</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That's close, can you do it without the extra space so it cuts out before the second column?

Comment: That requires the `empty-cells` property in CSS! Here is a reasonable [demo](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_empty-cells.asp) that you can look at